# Trying to insert JSON into MySQL with Node.JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, parsing

using **Node.JS** I have a **JSON** output I've received from an API call. I'm trying to insert this JSON into **MySQL** but I keep getting the error message:

*"Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`ANU`' at line 1"*

Why is it rejecting the input request and how can I rectify this?

Additionally, I'd rather include multiple fields such as *CountryName* and *CityName* - how could I do this?

When analysing the JSON file in node.JS 
`console.log(typeof JSON)` returns the output `[object Object]`

I think this is causing the error above as it is not in the correct format.

**Node.JS extract:**

```
//MySQL
let con = mysql.createConnection(config);
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected to MySQL!");

  var sql = "INSERT INTO TEST1 (CountryName) VALUES ?";
  var values = obj.LocationsResponse.Country[1].CountryName;
      con.query(sql, values, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
});
});
```

**JSON extract** (I have cleansed to keep it short):

```
obj = {"LocationsResponse":
{"Country":[
{"CountryName":"United Arab Emirates","CountryCode":"AE","City":[{"CityName":"Abu Dhabi","CityCode":"AUH"},{"CityName":"Dubai","CityCode":"DXB"}]}
,
{"CountryName":"Antigua","CountryCode":"AG","City":{"CityName":"Antigua","CityCode":"ANU"}}
,
{"CountryName":"USA","CountryCode":"US","City":
[{"CityName":"Albuquerque","CityCode":"ABQ",{"CityName":"Albany","CityCode":"ALB",{"CityName":"Amarillo","CityCode":"AMA",
{"CityName":"Anchorage","CityCode":"ANC"
}}}}]} 
]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON has nothing to do with this error.

You just got the syntax for INSERT wrong.

You have:

```
INSERT INTO TEST1 (CountryName) VALUES ?
```

You should have:

```
INSERT INTO TEST1 (CountryName) VALUES (?)
```

MySQL also supports an alternative syntax:

```
INSERT INTO TEST1 SET CountryName = ?
```

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert.html for more on MySQL's INSERT syntax.

Comment: Thanks! I will read up on this now. A few hours well spent haha.